# How to add UIWebView to CGContextRef PDF?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I am creating a PDF, I have added lots of NSString values into the PDF however I would like to now add some HTML styled text I have created into the PDF; the only thing is when I load it like a normal string like this:

```
[materialsHTML drawInRect:CGRectMake(55.0, 523.0, kDefaultPageWidth-100, 137.0) withAttributes:grayAttributes];
```

I lose all the formatting and all you can see is the html tags etc.

This is how I start my opening page, I was hoping someone could show me how to insert some kind of UIWebView.

```
// create some sample data. In a real application, this would come from the database or an API.
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleData" ofType:@"plist"];

    // get a temprorary filename for this PDF
    path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    self.pdfFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Job Sheet #%@.pdf", jobSheetNumber]];

    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    // This default is spelled out in the iOS documentation for UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(self.pdfFilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    // get the context reference so we can render to it.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // every student gets their own page
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);

///....
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(...); 
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(...); // load first uiwebview
// ...
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(...); // load second uiwebview
// ...
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: Unfortunatly not, that is making the whole PDF from a UIWebView, I am wanting to add two small UIWebviews to the pdf as layers i guess you would call it.

Comment: I think that update just creates a two page pdf... I have the pdf created fine, I was hoping to add two views inside my already created pdf that contain the html.